# How to get the text of the control from having Class and ClassnameNN using C#

Tags: c#, autoit-c#-wrapper

I can retrieve the text from a control using [AutoIt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt) easily with the [`ControlGetText`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlGetText.htm) function:

```
ControlGetText ("title", "text", controlID)
```

I need to do the same with C#. A full example including classes to import would be exactly what I need.

I've the following parameters of the control visible with AutoIt window information.

#### Class

"WindowsForms10.STATIC.app.0.33c0d9d"

#### ClassnameNN

"WindowsForms10.STATIC.app.0.33c0d9d62"

... Instance , Name, ID , handle,  **Text "7 - 18:50"** (this is the text I need to retrieve).

Preferably, I need to retrieve the text by using `Class` and `ClassnameNN`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how to send and get text using AutoIt in C#:

```
private void controlGetTextbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Open Notepad
    autoit.Run("notepad.exe", "", 1);

    //Wait for Notepad to open with a timeout of 10 seconds
    autoit.WinWait("[CLASS:Notepad]", "", 10);

    //Send text example
    autoit.ControlSend("[CLASS:Notepad]", "", "Edit1", "autoitsourcode.blogspot.com", 0);

    //Get the texts
    string strReturnText = autoit.ControlGetText("[CLASS:Notepad]", "", "Edit1");

    returnGetTextLabel.Text = "Return text from text area notepad : \n" + strReturnText;
}
```

Also, you can get all the AutoIt functions with C# at *[Autoit Control Get Text](http://autoitsourcecode.blogspot.com/2013/04/autoit-control-get-text.html)*.